# Adobe Flash Actionscript 3 collision detection within symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, collision-detection, flash-cs6

I'm learning actionscript and I'm trying to do a basic pong game from a tutorial but I'm having trouble with finding a way to properly code the collisions. Everything works but the collision wall extends past the edge of my symbol at the bottom of the screen. I need the entire game to be within a symbol so I can have it within a menu interface that I plan on later importing it into. You can find the code frame by double clicking the pong game.

My problem is in the code:

```
//if the bottom of the ball is lower than the bottom of the screen
if(ball.y >= stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2){ 
    ball.y = stage.stageHeight-ball.height/2; //reposition it
}
```

I need to find a way to change to code to detect collision based on the boundaries of the symbol or pixel height rather than stage height but I don't know how. You can download [the flash file](https://mega.co.nz/#!8FgVlJQS!b-H8T_Qxm9M7h2SDV4k6ld3R2hfUWWawCnAPc-8am9g) to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot that you are inside your `Pong` MovieClip which has the dimensions 550x400px which are different from your stage ones 960x540px and that's why your ball go out your black zone to your stage bottom border.

So you can :

- Put your code directly into your root timeline, and it will work fine.

Or

- Edit your current code to use your `Pong` MovieClip dimensions and not those of your stage.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what your saying but I'm not good enough at actionscript to implement these changes. I've tried altering the code but can't get it to work.

Comment: @Ross.ayl You have just to put `playerPaddle`, `ball` and `cpuPaddle` into your stage root timeline and copy the code of your `Pong`  MovieClip to the root timeline fist frame before removing that MovieClip.